# Why are there only installed applications in my Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-installation, software-center

For some reason all I see are a very small number of applications in the Ubuntu Software Center, and all of them are already installed. I thought I could use the software center to install new applications.

Comment: I guess you are viewing " installed " tab.  There is also " Ubuntu Software " for installing software other than software center in 16.04. Which version of Ubuntu are you in ?

Comment: No, I'm in the All tab. This is weird.